# Auto play video inside list

Tags: list, listview, swiftui, video

I want to create list of videos that auto play when the item in the center of the list.
I have tried to add play onAppear but the all the videos that visible are played.
Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
  
  @State private var player = AVPlayer()
  
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { reader in //
    List {
      ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { value in
        VStack{
          Text("Row \(value)")
          VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .frame(height: 200)
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
          
          if reader.size.height>500{
          player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "video.mp4")!)
          player.play()
          }
        }
        .onDisappear {
          player.pause()
        }
      }
    }
    .listStyle(.inset)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ScrollView and LazyVStack with a List

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var player = AVPlayer()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader1 in //
            List {
                ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { value in
                    GeometryReader { reader2 in
                        VStack{
                            Text("Row \(value)")
                            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                                .frame(height: 200)
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .onAppear {
                            if reader2.frame(in: .local).maxY >= reader1.frame(in: .local).midY {
                                player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "video.mp4")!)
                                player.play()
                            }
                        }
                        .onDisappear {
                            player.pause()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.inset)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't help, The video still playing together. Only one video should play when in center of the list.

Comment: yeah it's because the player needs to be re initialized with the url for each individual cell when it appears.

Comment: I re initialized with the url for each individual cell and still the problem exists.

Comment: show your code, can't help like this.

Comment: no not like that, I updated the answer right now.

if you wish to customise the behaviour even further you can decide when to play the video depending upon the position of the video player such as if it goes above a certain height on the screen while scrolling.

Comment: Ok now its better but play 3 videos together as all of them appear. How to make it play only at the position of the video like your sugssetion?

Comment: you can increase your vstack's frame so it takes up a big portion of your screen or you can use Geometry Reader or you can use UIScreen.main.bounds.midY (not recommended) if you want it to play only after it goes above the mid y value of the frame.

Comment: Well its a posts page so i cant use big portion of my screen for single post. I've tried with Geometry Reader but didn't succeed neither so frustrated me deleted the code. Any idea how to make it work with Geometry Reader?

Comment: use  UIScreen.main.bounds.midY

also update your code with your geometryreader, I want to see why it's not working.

Comment: I updated the code with geometry reader

Comment: updated my answer with geometryreader, lmk if it works.

Comment: Now when scrolling only the text changed. The video wont even played and wont change

Comment: Yeah avoid using GeometryReader then, it's weird. I would've suggested to use a built in way to check if the player is playing so no other video would play.
Unfortunately there's no way to do that in SwiftUI natively so you would have to make your view in UIKit and then use A NSNotificationCenter and observe AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification to know if your player has stopped playing so it can play the next video.

Comment: That wont help either. when the first video stops, the second video will play, even if its not in visible position.

Comment: no if it's inside the onAppear it will only run when it appears on the screen.

Comment: Yes but if two posts appear inside lists both are played together